# How to find dynamically next month and year using moment js in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

I have two calenders in my page which is implemented using full calender jQuery plugin.

I need to load calenders like left present calender and right upcoming month calender.Like if present is November then right calender should be december. Which i was able to do so by giving dates.

But i have two navigation arrows to navigate the calender at both left and right to these calenders. How can i get dynamic next month and year and vice-versa ie prev month and prev year provided a month and year.

I found a way to get current current month and year using moment.js which will handle leap year and all...

Below is the code so far to get current date. I need to know how can i get prev month and year and next month and year on navigation clicks.

Code:

```
var eNow = new Date();
var eMoment = moment(eNow);

var leftEMonth = eMoment.format('MM')-1; 
var leftEYear = eMoment.format('YYYY');
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Months:

```
moment().add(1, 'months');
```

Years:

```
moment().add(1, 'years');
```

So for example your *next month* button would look like this:

```
$('#nextMonthBtn').click(function () {
    eMoment.add(1, 'months');
});
```

assuming eMoment is in scope of course.

Comment: but moment().add(1, 'years'); only needs to happen on january 2015 right? how can we handle that with moment js

Comment: like i traverse from nov to dec year is 2014 but when i do the same from dec 2014 it should give jan 2015

Comment: It is a calendar, so `12/2014` plus one month equals `01/2015`